Making a multilingual searchbar
I have a searchbar on my website that can search the titles to the different pages on the website. It has an autocomplete function as well that can also change languages.


const langEls = [...document.querySelectorAll(".lang")];

let availableKeywords = {
  nl: [
    'pagina over katten',
    'pagina over honden',
    'pagina over kikkers'
  ],
  en: [
    'page about cats',
    'page about dogs',
    'page about frogs'
  ],
  es: [
   'pagina sobre gatos',
   'pagina sobre perros',
   'pagina sobre ranas'
  ],
  id: [
   'halaman tentang kucing',
   'halaman tentang anjing',
   'halaman tentang katak'
  ],
};

let chosenLanguage = 'en';

langEls.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
     const lang = el.dataset.lang;
    langEls.forEach(langEl => langEl.classList.remove('active'));
    el.classList.add('active');
     chosenLanguage = lang
     search()
  });
});
    

const resultsBox = document.querySelector(".result-box");
const inputBox = document.getElementById("query");
  
inputBox.onkeyup = search;
  
function display(result){
  const content = result.map((list)=>{
    return "<li onclick=selectInput(this)>" + list + "</li>";
  });

  resultsBox.innerHTML = "<ul>" + content.join('') + "</ul>";
}
  
function selectInput(list){
  inputBox.value = list.innerHTML;
  resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
}

function search(){
  let result = [];
  let input = inputBox.value;
  if(input.length){
    result = availableKeywords[chosenLanguage].filter((keyword)=>{
      return keyword.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase());
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
  display(result);

  if(!result.length){
    resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
  }
}   
.lang.active {
 color: red;
}
<div class="searchbar">
         <form id="form" role="search">
           <input type="text" id="query" name="q" placeholder="Search Here..." aria-label="Search through site content" autocomplete="off">
           <button>
             <span class="icon">
                <ion-icon name="search-outline"></ion-icon>
             </span>
           </button>
         </form>
         <div class="result-box">
         </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="langWrap">
        <a href="#" data-lang="nl" class="lang">NL</a>
        <a href="#" data-lang="en" class="lang active">EN</a>
        <a href="#" data-lang="es" class="lang">ES</a>
        <a href="#" data-lang="id" class="lang">ID</a>
      </div>



Is it possible so that if the user searches "page about cats" in any language, they get sent to cats.html. Or if they search "Page about dogs" they get sent to dogs.html? And if they search something that isn't on the website they get sent to 404.html? And if not, what would be a good alternative?
When i was running the site on localhost via vscode i used node.js to achieve the desired result (see code below), but that doesnt seem to work anymore now that im trying to run the site on a server so that i can put it online.
app.get("/page%20about%20cats", function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile("cats.html",{ root: path.join(__dirname, './public/pages') });
});


I think you can just change your search function to iterate over the languages you have


const langEls = [...document.querySelectorAll(".lang")];

let availableKeywords = {
  nl: [
    'pagina over katten',
    'pagina over honden',
    'pagina over kikkers'
  ],
  en: [
    'page about cats',
    'page about dogs',
    'page about frogs'
  ],
  es: [
   'pagina sobre gatos',
   'pagina sobre perros',
   'pagina sobre ranas'
  ],
  id: [
   'halaman tentang kucing',
   'halaman tentang anjing',
   'halaman tentang katak'
  ],
};

let chosenLanguage = 'en';

langEls.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
     const lang = el.dataset.lang;
    langEls.forEach(langEl => langEl.classList.remove('active'));
    el.classList.add('active');
     chosenLanguage = lang
     search()
  });
});
    

const resultsBox = document.querySelector(".result-box");
const inputBox = document.getElementById("query");
  
inputBox.onkeyup = search;
  
function display(result){
  const content = result.map((list)=>{
    return "<li onclick=selectInput(this)>" + list + "</li>";
  });

  resultsBox.innerHTML = "<ul>" + content.join('') + "</ul>";
}
  
function selectInput(list){
  inputBox.value = list.innerHTML;
  resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
}

function search(){
  let result = [];
  let input = inputBox.value;
  if(input.length) {
    ['nl', 'es', 'en', 'id'].forEach((lang) => {
      result = result.concat(availableKeywords[lang].filter((keyword)=>{
        return keyword.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase());
  }));
}
    console.log(result);
  });
  display(result);

  if(!result.length){
    resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
  }
}   
.lang.active {
 color: red;
}
<div class="searchbar">
         <form id="form" role="search">
           <input type="text" id="query" name="q" placeholder="Search Here..." aria-label="Search through site content" autocomplete="off">
           <button>
             <span class="icon">
                <ion-icon name="search-outline"></ion-icon>
             </span>
           </button>
         </form>
         <div class="result-box">
         </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="langWrap">
        <a href="#" data-lang="nl" class="lang">NL</a>
        <a href="#" data-lang="en" class="lang active">EN</a>
        <a href="#" data-lang="es" class="lang">ES</a>
        <a href="#" data-lang="id" class="lang">ID</a>
      </div>





const langEls = [...document.querySelectorAll(".lang")];

let availableKeywords = {
  nl: [
    'pagina over katten',
    'pagina over honden',
    'pagina over kikkers'
  ],
  en: [
    'page about cats',
    'page about dogs',
    'page about frogs'
  ],
  es: [
   'pagina sobre gatos',
   'pagina sobre perros',
   'pagina sobre ranas'
  ],
  id: [
   'halaman tentang kucing',
   'halaman tentang anjing',
   'halaman tentang katak'
  ],
};

let chosenLanguage = 'en';

langEls.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
     const lang = el.dataset.lang;
    langEls.forEach(langEl => langEl.classList.remove('active'));
    el.classList.add('active');
     chosenLanguage = lang
     search()
  });
});
    

const resultsBox = document.querySelector(".result-box");
const inputBox = document.getElementById("query");
  
inputBox.onkeyup = search;
  
function display(result){
  const content = result.map((list)=>{
    return "<li onclick=selectInput(this)>" + list + "</li>";
  });

  resultsBox.innerHTML = "<ul>" + content.join('') + "</ul>";
}
  
function selectInput(list){
  inputBox.value = list.innerHTML;
  resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
}

function search(){
  let result = [];
  let input = inputBox.value;
  if(input.length){
    ['nl', 'en', 'es', 'id'].forEach((lang) => {
    result = result.concat(availableKeywords[lang].filter((keyword)=>{
      return keyword.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase());
    }));
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
  display(result);

  if(!result.length){
    resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
  }
}   
.lang.active {
 color: red;
}
<div class="searchbar">
         <form id="form" role="search">
           <input type="text" id="query" name="q" placeholder="Search Here..." aria-label="Search through site content" autocomplete="off">
           <button>
             <span class="icon">
                <ion-icon name="search-outline"></ion-icon>
             </span>
           </button>
         </form>
         <div class="result-box">
         </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="langWrap">
        <a href="#" data-lang="nl" class="lang">NL</a>
        <a href="#" data-lang="en" class="lang active">EN</a>
        <a href="#" data-lang="es" class="lang">ES</a>
        <a href="#" data-lang="id" class="lang">ID</a>
      </div>




Thank you for your response. The snippet you made doesnt work for me though? it just shows the entire list of keywords and doesnt filter them anymore. It also doesnt really answer the question on how a certain keyword can send the user to the according webpage

@Pascal what do you mean by "doesnt filter them anymore" ?
when I type "c", I get
[
  "page about cats",
  "halaman tentang kucing"
]

when I type "ca" I get
[
  "page about cats"
]

